# XmlSerialization of collections

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

I want to serialize the following Xml structure:

```
  <XmlRootElement>
     <Company name="Acme Widgets LLC">
        <DbApplication name="ApplicationA" vendor="oracle">
           <ConnSpec environment="DEV" 
                     server="DBOraDev1201" 
                     database="AppA" 
                     userId="MyUser" 
                     password="5613456#6%^%$%$#" />
           <ConnSpec environment="QA" 
                     server="DBOraQA1205" 
                     database="AppA" 
                     userId="MyUser" 
                     password="5613456#6%^%$%$#" />
       </DbApplication>
       <DbApplication name="AnotherApp" "vendor="SQLServer">
           <ConnSpec environment="DEV" 
                     server="DBMsSqlDev1201" 
                     catalog="AnoptherApp" 
                     userId="MyUser" 
                     password="5613456#6%^%$%$#" />
           <ConnSpec environment="QA" 
                     server="DBMsSqlQA1565" 
                     catalog="AnotherApp" 
                     userId="MyUser" 
                     password="5613456#6%^%$%$#" />
       </DbApplication>
     </Company>
     <Company name = "ExpertSoftware Inc" ....
        ...
     </Company>
  </XmlRootElement>
```

but I have discovered in [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx)

Quote from above link:
...

- Q: Why aren't all properties of
  collection classes serialized?
- A: The XmlSerializer only serializes
  the elements in the collection when
  it detects either the IEnumerable or
  the ICollection interface. This
  behavior is by design. The only work
  around is to re-factor the custom
  collection into two classes, one of
  which exposes the properties
  including one of the pure collection
  types.

...

after discovering that you can't serialize or deserialize a collection that has other Xml attributes in it... The suggested workaround is to separate the element that has the collection from the the ones that have other attributes... i.e, You have to change the structure so that it looks like this instead:

```
  <XmlRootElement>
     <Companys>
        <Company name="Acme Widgets LLC">
           <DbApplications>
               <DbApplication name="ApplicationA" vendor="oracle">
                  <ConnSpecs>
                     <ConnSpec environment="DEV" 
                         server="DBOraDev1201" ...  />
                     <ConnSpec environment="QA" 
                         server="DBOraQA1205" 
                         database="AppA" ... />
                  </ConnSpecs>
               </DbApplication>
               <DbApplication name="AnotherApp" "vendor="SQLServer">
                  <ConnSpecs>
                      <ConnSpec environment="DEV" ... />
                      <ConnSpec environment="QA"  ... />
                  </ConnSpecs>
                </DbApplication>
           </DbApplications>
         </Company>
         <Company name = "ExpertSoftware Inc" ....
             ...
         </Company>
     </Companys>
  </XmlRootElement>
```

Does anyone know why this is so? or if there is some other way to do this?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what your problem is.  I serialize/deserialize collections all the time.  What error are you getting?

Comment: I cannot serialize or deserialize into an object graph where the Xml element which "contains" multiple child elements also has attributes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) you need to indicate it how to serialize your collections:

```
public class XmlRootElement
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Company")]
    public Company[] Company { get; set; }

    // Other properties ....
}

public class Company
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DbApplication")]
    public DbApplication[] DbApplication { get; set; }

    // Other properties ....
}

public class DbApplication
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ConnSpec")]
    public ConnSpec[] ConnSpec { get; set; }

    // Other properties ....
}

public class ConnSpec
{
    // Other properties ....
}
```

And then:

```
using (Stream stream = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlRootElement));
    XmlRootElement root = (XmlRootElement)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: For other elements (not collection elements) you only have to do this if the element name is different from the class name... But I will try this...

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to adding XMl serialization attributes to all of your classes is to implement the [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) interface on the root element container class. The **ReadXml** and **WriteXml** methods of this interface will be used by the XmlSerializer, allowing you to have more fine grained control over the serialization/deserialization process.